# String comparison not working (android)

Tags: java, android, string, comparison

My string comparison is not working. I do not know why. It returns that it is always equal even when the two strings are not the same

here is the code Im using

```
if(videoFile.equals(LangSelect.INSTRUCTION_01));
    {
        Log.i("InstructionVideo", "video and instruction are equal\n"+ videoFile + "\n" + LangSelect.INSTRUCTION_01);

        //hideBackButton();
    }
```

The videoFile is intro_x.mp4 where x changes to number from 0 to 4 while INSTRUCTION_01 is into_0.mp4

the part of my onCreate that does sets videoFile variable

```
    //get which video file to play
    videoFile = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PlayVideo");

    Log.i("InstructionVideo", "videoFile name: " +videoFile);
```

Here is the LogCat of that portion

```
 05-15 14:59:57.078: I/InstructionVideo(2952): videoFile name: intro_0.mp4
 05-15 14:59:57.085: I/InstructionVideo(2952): video and instruction are equal
 05-15 14:59:57.085: I/InstructionVideo(2952): intro_0.mp4
 05-15 14:59:57.085: I/InstructionVideo(2952): intro_0.mp4
 05-15 14:59:57.124: I/surfaceCreated(2952): created
 05-15 14:59:58.324: I/LangSelect(2952): 7
 05-15 14:59:58.390: I/InstructionVideo(2952): videoFile name: intro_1.mp4
 05-15 14:59:58.390: I/InstructionVideo(2952): video and instruction are equal 
 05-15 14:59:58.390: I/InstructionVideo(2952): intro_1.mp4
 05-15 14:59:58.390: I/InstructionVideo(2952): intro_0.mp4
 05-15 14:59:58.433: I/surfaceCreated(2952): created
 05-15 14:59:58.484: I/SurfaceDestroyed(2952): destroyed
 05-15 15:00:07.382: I/LangSelect(2952): 7
 05-15 15:00:07.445: I/InstructionVideo(2952): videoFile name: intro_2.mp4
 05-15 15:00:07.449: I/InstructionVideo(2952): video and instruction are equal
 05-15 15:00:07.449: I/InstructionVideo(2952): intro_2.mp4
 05-15 15:00:07.449: I/InstructionVideo(2952): intro_0.mp4
 05-15 15:00:07.488: I/surfaceCreated(2952): created
 05-15 15:00:07.539: I/SurfaceDestroyed(2952): destroyed
 05-15 15:00:23.535: I/LangSelect(2952): 7
 05-15 15:00:23.597: I/InstructionVideo(2952): videoFile name: intro_3.mp4
 05-15 15:00:23.597: I/InstructionVideo(2952): video and instruction are equal
 05-15 15:00:23.597: I/InstructionVideo(2952): intro_3.mp4
 05-15 15:00:23.597: I/InstructionVideo(2952): intro_0.mp4
 05-15 15:00:23.632: I/surfaceCreated(2952): created
 05-15 15:00:23.687: I/SurfaceDestroyed(2952): destroyed
 05-15 15:00:38.843: I/LangSelect(2952): 7
 05-15 15:00:38.902: I/InstructionVideo(2952): videoFile name: intro_4.mp4
 05-15 15:00:38.906: I/InstructionVideo(2952): video and instruction are equal
 05-15 15:00:38.906: I/InstructionVideo(2952): intro_4.mp4
 05-15 15:00:38.906: I/InstructionVideo(2952): intro_0.mp4
 05-15 15:00:38.941: I/surfaceCreated(2952): created
 05-15 15:00:38.992: I/SurfaceDestroyed(2952): destroyed
 05-15 15:01:13.242: I/LangSelect(2952): 7
 05-15 15:01:13.296: I/SurfaceDestroyed(2952): destroyed
```

It shows that even as i compare them they return true but are not

Comment: Is it always resulting `true` ?

Comment: yes always resulting true. I have used compareTo, ==, even contains all return that they are true

Comment: Are you sure it is changing? Strings are immutable in Java. How are you generating those strings?

Comment: Show us the declaration of `LangSelect.INSTRUCTION_01` and also how you set the variable `videoFile` to different values

Comment: They are passed from a previous activity. Via an intent. LangSelect.INSTRUCTION_01 is a static string while videoFile is changed each time the activity is called

Comment: So if your Intent failed to send the extra what is the default value? you should really paste a complete code example into your question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a `;` at the end of the "if" line, which terminates the "if" statement, therefore the following block is always executed.

Comment: Funny how you don't see what you're not looking for - I missed it skimming over the question.

Comment: @Jonathon You're telling me. Ive been sitting on this for like 30 minutes and it kept failing .

Comment: I've thrown a `false &&` in front of other conditionals in the past if a conditional block is being entered when I *really* don't expect it to.  If it still enters the block, you look closely at every piece of punctuation.

Comment: yea I have a couple of areas where i used String == String before but now Im changing it to compareTO or Contains hopefully without adding the semicolon at the end